# How to find current directory in C inside an application bundle [macOS]

Tags: c, macos, perl

We have an application bundle whose main executable has been written in Perl and packaged with pp. Unfortunately, this executable prevents us to codesign the .app. Apparently executables created with pp cannot be codesigned. To allow codesigning we want to move the main executable from its default folder "MacOS" to the "Resources" folder, as this folder seems to be okay to host the executable for codesigning and create a launcher that will run this executable. We do not know if this will work, but we want to give it a try.

We need to create a launcher to put in the "MacOS" folder that will launch our main executable. I have worked out a small C program that launches an executable in another folder. It works fine in Finder, however it fails if in the .app structure. Apparently it has to do with the relative path being different inside a .app. My hope is to add to the following C program a way to get the current directory of the .app and construct the relative path to the executable to be opened. Being the first time I write something in C, I need your help to make this adaptation.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main( void ){

int result ;
result=system("../Resources/MyApp");
printf("%d", result);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what do you want to do but `pwd` is something that you looking for. In first block of code you will receive full path of the working directory and in second with `int result` you can know is operation done sucessfully (if result = 0 than is OK)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* dir= malloc (50);
    dir = getenv("pwd");
    printf("Workdir: %s\n", dir);
    free(dir);

    int result;
    result = system("pwd");
    printf("%d", result);
    return 0;
}
```

then you can edit the full path and create relative.

Comment: When compiling I get the following error: run.c:9:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mi'
    free(mi);
         ^
1 error generated.

Comment: Ok, just put dir instead mi. I just copy paste code

Comment: It compiles. Thank you. One last question, having never worked with C before. How can I modify the path in result = system("pwd") so that I can call an executable which is one level up from the current path and is called myApp. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Tell me how do you run the app from Terminal? `system("command")` will run command just like in Terminal. So try `.././myApp`

Comment: No, I need to run the C code inside .app as the default executable by double clicking the .app . The C code should then run the proper program which is in a different folder inside the .app structure. My first C code calls correctly MyApp which is in a different directory. I run my C code in Terminal just with ./launcher (being launcher my C code), and it works. However, inside an .app structure this does not work because the .app changes the current directory. I need to force the current directory to the correct one in my C code to call the executable MyApp properly. I hope this clarifies.